deleting objects from a sub folder in S3 bucket
I am trying to delete objects that exist in S3 bucket sub folder. Below is what I am trying to do in C#:
string subBucketName = "TS-AP/";
var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));

amazonS3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.DeleteObjectRequest() { BucketName = BucketName, Key = subBucketName + "/" + d.StoredFileName});

In the above code, subBucketName is the sub folder inside S3 bucket so  my bucketName is "Connect" and the sub folder name is "TS-AP". The file that I want to delete exists in "TS-AP" sub folder. when I run the above code, the code does not throw any error, it just runs, but I don't see the files deleted in the S3 bucket.
any help will be appreciated.

If you add a debug statement to print subBucketName + "/" + d.StoredFileName, does it exactly match the Key of the object as shown in the S3 management console?

The file name and sub folder name is exactly same. The only difference is one single slash. Not sure if I need 2 slash or one slash. I will try two s;lash right now. The sub folder name is like this :  "TS-AP/"

actually, the sub folder name is "TS-AP/"

Does it work if you hard-code the filename? Example: { BucketName = BucketName, Key = "TS-AP/file1"});

No, it doesn't. The file still exists in sub folder. Is it possible that there is a delayed delete.

The double-slash in your code will make Key = 'TS-AP//file1', which won't work. Deletes are immediate. Sub-folders don't actually exist in S3 -- instead, the Key contains the full path of the object. Are you 100% sure you have the right Bucket and Key? Please note that if the object being deleted does not exist, it will not throw an error. I suggest you Copy the key from the S3 console and paste it as hard-coded for the moment, to verify no typing errors.

You were right. It was the key issue. I copied and pasted the key and it worked! I wish I was getting an error in the code then it would be easier. Thank you for all your help!

The double-slash in your code will make Key = 'TS-AP//file1', which won't work.
Deletes are immediate.
Sub-folders don't actually exist in S3 -- instead, the Key contains the full path of the object.
Are you 100% sure you have the right Bucket and Key? Please note that if the object being deleted does not exist, it will not throw an error.
I suggest you Copy the key from the S3 console and paste it as hard-coded for the moment, to verify no typing errors.

Thank you. I copied and pasted the key and it worked!
